# IPTables configuration for Transparent Proxy

Tags: proxy, iptables

I am confuse why my IPTable does not work in Router. what I'm trying to do is redirect any packets from source ip destined to port 80 and 443 to  192.168.1.110:3128. however when I tried this:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.5 -p tcp --dport 80:443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.110:3128
```

does not work. however when I add this,

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING-j MASQUARADE
```

it works. but the problem with masquarade is I do not get the real ip but instead the ip of the router. I need to get the source ip so my proxy server could record all ip connected to it. can some one tell me how to make it work without making POSTROUTING jump to Masquarade?

Comment: as long is it is NAT you'll need masquerading

Comment: is there other way I could retain its original ip so once it reach my proxy server I get its real ip rather than the ip of my router?

Comment: I guess your problem is that proxy cannot reply to your machine, because it have no route to it. Try adding route for one address (on proxy server, to client), with your router as a gateway. NAT requires much less attention, maybe you need some other way to authenticate your clients.

Answer (score 6):

For **real transparent proxying you need to use the TPROXY target** (in the mangle table, PREROUTING chain). All other iptables-mechanisms like any NAT, MASQUERADE, REDIRECT rewrite the IP addresses of the packet, which makes it impossible to find out where the packet originally was intended to.

The proxy program has to bind() and listen() on a socket like any other server, but needs some specific socket flags (which requires some Linux capabilities (type of permission) or root). – Once connected, there is some way to get the “intended server” from the OS.

Sorry, I’m a little lazy about the details, but searching for “TPROXY” as keyword will get you going quickly!

Comment: Yes and no. HTTP/1.1 clients will send the server name in the Host header and many HTTPS clients support SNI. This makes NAT good enough for some usecase.

Comment: @Alex "Yes" to what and "no" to what?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Yes, you're correct that the destination address is not easily made available to the server process. That said, for HTTP & HTTPS the protocol iteself contains the server host name which may be good enough.

Comment: @AlexJasmin I just couldn’t stand that this question about transparent proxies had no answer talking about real transparent proxying! The rest are crutches.

Answer (score 5):

If I am not wrong, the correct syntax of the rule would be:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.5 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.110:3128
```

`--dport 80:443` will forward all ports from 80 to 443 
`--dports 80,443` will forward port 80 and 443 only.

If you want traffic hitting 192.168.1.5 on port 80 and 443 to be forwarded to 192.168.1.110's 3128 port then you should use the below rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.5 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.110:3128
```

You should also make sure the gateway on 192.168.1.110 is pointed to your router ip.

Finally you can use the masquerade rule as below.

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

eth1 should be your outgoing interface.

Comment: what if proxy requires authentication?

Comment: Don't forget to enable IP forwarding (this took me way too long): `sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution was to tell the transparent proxy to forward the source ip in the right header fields.
In case of my nginx proxy the rules were close to:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://name_of_proxy;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i used the `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s foreign ip to your device --dport 80:443 -j DNAT --to-destination your application or local ip:port`.i think you did the prerouting the packet in your device out which never connect to port 80 or 443,these is for web server connect to device.192.168.1.5 is like my local address.

and remember to config`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing NAT in both directions by not specifying an interface.  Try adding `-o eth0` to your `-j MASQUERADE` line.  (Substitute whatever your "external" interface is, instead of `eth0`, depending on your setup.)